# Incorporating Add Data step in ModelBuilder for ArcGIS Pro to create multidimensional raster from NetCDF file

Tags: arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, interpolation, netcdf

There are functions in ArcGIS Pro to read in NetCDF files and create a single value raster but in order to create a multi-dimensional raster one needs to use Add Data and select multidimensional raster as the desired output.  This option also allows one to interpolate values using nearest neighbor sampling which is necessary if the provided coordinate values are not quite equally spaced (as in our case).  We wish to incorporate this step into a ModelBuilder process because we have hundreds of NetCDF files to process.